# How to pass a variable's value form a Java Class to JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am calling a web service in which I need to shows some messages in a jsp page based on some conditions. I need to show the value of this variable in a JSP if it is not null. Looks like it is not working at all.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Java

```
private String emailValidationMessage;

public String getEmailValidationMessage() {
    return emailValidationMessage;
}

public void setEmailValidationMessage(String emailValidationMessage) {
    this.emailValidationMessage = emailValidationMessage;
}

if( validateEmailAddressResponse.isVerifiedEmailDomain() == false && 
    validateEmailAddressResponse.isVerifiedEmailFormat() == false ) {
    setEmailValidationMessage( UiIntegrationKeyConstants.EMAIL_VALIDATION_CODE_EE01 );
}
```

JSP

```
<div>
   <table width=100%>
     <tr>
         <c:if test="${emailValidationMessage != null}">
            <td class="fieldLabelBold" style="color:#0033CC" align="center">${emailValidationMessage}</td>
        </c:if>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Am I doing it in a wrong way? I don't want to pass it as a URL param.

Thanks...

Comment: JSP is mostly for rendering HTML, and a web service rarely returns HTML, so question does make a lot of sense. Anyway, how is your Java class executed? What web service framework are you using?

Comment: Your variable is set in which object. How does the JSP finds this object? Did you import it and is the object available in current scope?
You should not use values in JSP directly. Instead JSTL or any template library should be used so you don't mix Views and Model.

Comment: I am using Strust2 and the variable is in UiIntegrationManager class.

Comment: @Andreas. I am using Jersey with Strust2. Basically I am validating an email address. If validation fails I need to display the message returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are other ways to achieve this,
1.El expression is one of this to achieve this.
2.You can use to set the values in sessions,

`session.setAttribute("sessionName""someValue");`

and call it in your JSP page as

`String value = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionName") == null ? "":(string)session.getAttribute("sessionName");`

,here you will get the value from session.Check whether it is null or not! It it is null,don't show,if else,show value.
You can use two ways to display,1.Using Expression tags`<%=%>` or using javascript/jquery, by setting the value to the respected tags using their own id. For [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) and for [Jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp). Using jquery/javascript,you can give additional effects as well.Hope this may help.Thankyou.